# MySQL - is it legal to do 'SELECT table1.*,table2.column FROM table1,table2'?

Tags: mysql

MySQL - is it legal to do `'SELECT table1.*,table2.column FROM table1,table2'`?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: If your aim was to ask whether the above SQL was the best way to achieve what you wanted then you should have asked that instead.

Comment: @Gal: And for the record, I didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is legal, but it will give you a Cartesian product of the two tables. Are you sure that you want a Cartesian Product?

Most times, you would use a JOIN as in:

```
Select Table1.*, Table2,ColumnName
From Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2
        ON Table1.PKColumn = Table2.FKColumn
```

Comment: For those of you running for the dictionary *(which I did, even tho I knew what he was talking about xD)*, here a Cartesian Product means; all possible combinations of rows from both tables. Two tables with 5 rows each, joined in this manner, will result in a 25 row result set. Not ideal in most cases.

Comment: `cross join` is a more common term for it

Answer (score 0):

While this theta syntax is legal, it's just too easy to miss a join condition without the parser warning you.