# CodeIgniter activerecord how column = column in where clause

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using CodeIgniter with activerecord to access my database, 
I am wondering if I want to write a query like this:

```
Select * from table1, table2
whher table1.id = table2.id
```

I tried this:

```
$where = array("table1.id" => "table2.id");     
$query = $this->db->get_where("table1, table2" , $where);   
return $query->result();
```

But it gives me an error because it compiled to be like:

```
select * from table1, table2 
where table1.id = 'table2.id'
```

So how to tell that I want a columns is equal to another column in activerecord in codeIgniter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can simply try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table1.id = 25");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

With active records

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.id = table1.id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('table2.id', 007);
```

> > **I saw your [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003175/codeiniger-activerecord-how-column-column-in-where-clause#comment57734852_35003301) on @Kisaragi answer. No you can do that. You cant get data from multiple table without join those tables to together.**

Comment: Thanks, this solution will work, but I want to keep using activerecord class instead of writing plain query

Comment: Both CI define mathods

Comment: @MohanadKaleia check now

Comment: Okay, yes seems this is the only solution

Comment: I saw your comment, but I can get data without using plain join, like:
select * from table1, table2
where 
table1.id = table2.id

So no need to use join, right?

Comment: @MohanadKaleia No you cant check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814144/mysql-is-it-legal-to-do-select-table1-table2-column-from-table1-table2

Comment: @MohanadKaleia happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join clause in stead

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('table2 as t2','t2.id=t1.id');
$this->db->get('table1 as t1');
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is also working, butI don't like to use a lot of join clauses, it is strange that there is no simple thing to compare two columns in where clause!

Comment: You can use a `having count > 1` clause as well. It's much easier to just join.